# Conversion between NSData and void *

Tags: objective-c, c

In my iPhone app, I have to use MQTT's C based static library to send and receive its payload, the payload must be void *, I need to send messages such as text, picture and voice
This is my sending method, I warp all kind of payloads into NSData object. And the message is a struct which have the void *payload

```
`+ (int)send:(NSString *)mqTopic payLoad:(NSData *)mqPayLoad`

MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
pubmsg.payloadlen = mqPayLoad;
```

How can I fix the type conflict between C and ojbc?

Any help should be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSData has a method `- (const void *)bytes`. So this should help resolve the type conflict you are facing.

```
NSUInteger len = [mqPayLoad length];
void *typedData = malloc(len);
memcpy(typedData, [mqPayLoad bytes], len);
pubmsg.payloadlen = typedData;
```

Since bytes returns a `const void*` its better to use a `memcopy()` rather than a typecast.

Comment: You can use the -getBytes:length: method instead of memcpy+bytes. This will also be (much) faster if the NSData is discontiguous.

Comment: @Catfish_Man I tried -getBytes:length:, Xcode turned out a EXC_BAD_ACCESS message. I'm very new to develop iPhone app, can you give some example code for this?

Comment: @Suhas Now I come across with another problem. I receive the payload with NSData *data=[NSData dataWithBytes:payload length:payloadLen], it turns out to be garbled. Could u do me a favor?

Comment: -getBytes:length: example: NSUInteger len = [mqPayLoad length]; void *data = malloc(len); [mqPayLoad getBytes:data length:len];